# Fully developed DDD and Onion architecture sample

Tags: domain-driven-design, onion-architecture

I started designing one console application with domain driven design and onion architecture, before doing that i want to explore a fully designed application with domain driven design and onion architecture. If you come across any kind of sample please post the link to it.

Comment: For onion architecture, try searching for examples of ports & adapters and hexagonal architectures.  These 3 architectures are very similar.  For DDD there's not many examples because each DDD solution should be built according to the domain it is attempting to model.

Comment: I want to use them in a combination, complimenting each other. I did a search but no luck. If any body come across the solutions and samples where ddd and onion architecture used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same question as you and came to the following conclusion: You won't find a complete DDD example as it does not exist.

A proper DDD application will scream domain and not framework. When you look at the code you will see an accounting system or a scheduling system, not a DDD system.

I would suggest you take each part, starting with entity, aggregate root, application boundary and repository and start implementing them 1 by 1. When you get stuck, look for solutions to your specific problem.

**Update**

I found this book by Vaughn Vernon https://vaughnvernon.co/?page_id=168

I will be starting a series on implementing DDD in .net on my [blog](http://sneakycode.net/) soon.

Comment: _"A proper DDD application will scream domain and not framework"_ Exactly! DDD focuses on defining the Ubiquitous Language and modeling your domain. It has nothing to do with any kind of framework or architecture. I've blogged about this, you might want to have a look: [DDD is not architecture](https://onehundredacorns.wordpress.com/2014/10/13/ddd-is-not-architecture/).

Comment: @SneakyPeet IDDD is an amazing book ;)

Comment: Does the book talks about Onion Architecture too ?